# Ошибка при выполнении программы c++

Tags: c++, массивы, память

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char *writeInt(int v)
{
    char lol[] = {};
    lol[0] = (((v >> 24) & 0xFF));
    lol[1] = (((v >> 16) & 0xFF));
    lol[2] = (((v >>  8) & 0xFF));
    lol[3] = (((v      ) & 0xFF));
}
int readInt(char i[])
{
    return (
            ((i[0] << 24) & 0xFF) |
            ((i[1] << 16) & 0xFF) |
            ((i[2] <<  8) & 0xFF) |
             (i[3]        & 0xFF));
}
int main()
{
    writeInt(10);
    std::cout << readInt(writeInt(10)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Выдает Segmentation fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char lol[] = {};
```

Ну, т.е. пустое место. Ни одного элемента в массиве, но все равно пишем? уже достаточно для проблем... Кстати, тот же VC++ этот код не скомпилирует - нулевых массивов не бывает. Но даже если исправить - что вы собираетесь вернуть? Ведь `return` во `writeInt` нет - оно же опять не компилируется!

Вывод: или вы пользуетесь калечным компилятором, или вводите нас в заблуждение :)

Вот так - еще куда ни шло:

```
unsigned char *writeInt(int v)
{
    static unsigned char lol[4];
    lol[0] = (((v >> 24) & 0xFF));
    lol[1] = (((v >> 16) & 0xFF));
    lol[2] = (((v >>  8) & 0xFF));
    lol[3] = (((v      ) & 0xFF));
    return lol;
}
int readInt(unsigned char i[])
{
    return (
            ((i[0] << 24) ) |
            ((i[1] << 16) ) |
            ((i[2] <<  8) ) |
             (i[3]        ));
}
int main()
{
    writeInt(10);
    std::cout << readInt(writeInt(10)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Язык С++ не допускает таких объявлений в принципе

```
char lol[] = {};
```

Программа некорректна. Любые попытки выполнения такой "программы" приводят к неопределенному поведению, проявлением которого запросто может быть и Segmentation fault.